# Propose new tag (translation-request)

Tags: discussion, tagging, languages

I created a new tag `(translation-request)` on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246638/russian-translation). This isn't the first time I've seen someone post a translation request, though I'm not finding any others at the moment. I surmise that they may all have been closed and deleted as "off-topic", as the post for which I created the tag is well on its way to being closed, itself.

I submit that this tag may be worth keeping around, however. One could of course go to another site intended to translate from the first language to the second, but often, such sites are incapable of translating the more specialized mathematical terminology correctly. Moreover, I've seen several people comment on awkwardly worded posts, suggesting that the user post in their native tongue, and ask someone to translate the post to English for them, so I know that such requests wouldn't necessarily be out of place.

Obviously, we don't want Math-SE to become a site largely devoted to translation, rather than answering mathematical questions, but it seems that in some contexts, it would be appropriate. Perhaps it would be better if there were a meta post devoted to translation requests (such as the reopen request post), to avoid clogging the main site with such requests.

I'd like to know what the thoughts of the community are regarding the possibility of keeping this tag around permanently, or how we should handle requests for translation in general.

I see that robjohn has recently added [this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6690/translation-of-mathematical-questions), so apparently, I'm not the only one curious about this.

Comment: I found this post because I disagreed with the closure of the post you linked to.

Comment: Some language-related questions have been closed as off-topic, but [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59801/translation-from-french) and [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219737/what-is-the-gender-of-k-pi-n-in-french) (a question on the grammatical gender in French of a certain space) didn't receive any close votes and were answered. In my opinion language-related questions are legitimate questions because the community here is most likely to be able to answer them, more so than at sites like http://german.stackexchange.com.

Comment: There is a difference between "language-related questions" and translation requests.